# How to define a conditional variable based on active drop-down selection

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I've created a simple form using jquery 'chosen' library.   This form constructs an iframe src where the url contains the selections made by the user.

One requirement was to only allow the user to make a selection from 1 of the first two drop-downs (AttributeTree OR  Disease) which i've managed to do successfully, where the drop-down not in use is disabled.

Now the issue I have is for my variable  URL:

```
URL = reportURL +  Tree  + Disease + Country + Gender
```

I need this to be dynamic so that when the user has selected an AttributeTree (drop-down 1) then the URL should be 
`URL = reportURL +  Tree  + Country + Gender`

..and when the user has selected Disease  (drop-down 2) then the URL should be 
`URL = reportURL +  Disease + Country + Gender`

If I keep it the way it is it includes the redundant filter and text in my URL (for the filter not in use) which creates in invalid URL.

I have a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bentham7246/3916ht7d/195/)  which i'm using to create this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery "is" function to check whether it is disabled or not.
Here is my code.

```
var Tree = $("#Selection1").is(":disabled")?"":"Trees/JDAttribute2 in (" + $("#Selection1").val() + ") and ";
var Disease = $("#Selection2").is(":disabled")?"":"Diseases/DiseaseKey in ("   + $("#Selection2").val() + ") and ";
var Country = "Countries/CountryKey in ("   + $("#Selection3").val() + ") and ";
var Gender = "Genders/GenderKey in ("   + $("#Selection4").val() + ")";

var URL = reportURL +  Tree  + Disease + Country + Gender ;
```

I saved your fiddle.